# using wordnet to find terms with no noun synsets or at least one noun synset

Tags: wordnet

I am using WordNet 3.0. The WordNet documentation shows how to find synsets of a given word such as:

```
 wn car -synsn
```

But, is there a way to find terms with
  a) no noun synsets 
  b) with at least one noun synset and so on.

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: 
*"NO! There is no way to search based on existence or count of words in synset"*

Neither the Command Line interface nor the Library API provide the ability to apply this kind of predicates to a search.

This said, it is possible to import WordNet files to a more relational type of storage, and perform this type of queries in the resulting database.
The more direct way to import WordNet data is by tapping directly into the WordNet files themselves (see in particular [these two files](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/wndb.5WN.html) and parsing out the desired data.
An alternative is to build some kind of scanner of the data based on the Library API, hence leveraging all the WordNet format parsing capability of the library, and to output the desired Fields to a text file more suitable for database import.